# QGIS Label Rule

Tags: qgis, expression

I want to create rule based labeling for a layer where I want to label any features that have "private" anywhere in the value under "ROAD_NAME"

So if I had  Values:

Highway 1
Highway 2
Road 1
Road 2
Private 1
Private 2

I want to label all values except the ones that have "private" anywhere in their name. Is there an expression that uses a wildcard character or something similar to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use the `regexp_match` function under `String` in the expression builder to do this.

Something like:

```
  NOT (regexp_match( "ROAD_NAME",'\\bPrivate\\b') >= 0)
```

while find all the features where "ROAD_NAME" doesn't contain `Private` as a single word.

Comment: What is the \\b for?

Comment: it is a word boundary marker, this makes sure that words containing private don't get matched